# OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied in reverseShell.py

Tags: python, pipe, permission-denied, python-2.5, reverse-shell

I've tried to build a reverse Shell via python. Shell server works perfectly, but reverseShell.py doesn't. I was using Metasploitable vfstp 2.3.4 Backdoor to get into it, so it's using python 2.5.

```
File "reverseShell.py", line 17, in <module>
    proc = Popen(command.split(" "), stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/subprocess.py", line 594, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/subprocess.py", line 1147, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I've tried giving chmod -R 777 permission, but it still points out the same problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You may want to `print(command.split(" ")[0])`, and run it manually, and run `ls -l` on all pathname components.

Comment: A correct sequence of `chmod 777`s should fix it.